# How to convert/Play *.STR files in PC

Tags: video, video-streaming, converters, television

I recorded a show from my TV on Airtel DTH (in India) in a Pen drive. I can play the recorded show in my TV, however, I am unable to find any way to play the recorded video on my PC.

After searching a lot I came to know that the video is stored as STR format file. I browsed my pen drive in my PC, and found the .STR file. But now I would like to know how I will be able to play the video on my PC.